# Gauges Charts - multiple gauges java

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts and I'm trying to add multiple charts to one json call.

The chart style is gauge.

The example below works for only one gauge "field1" I'm not that great with the charts but I did create a working example that updates.

What I want to add is two more gauges and the json array names would be Tlak,Vlhkost. So the json would look something like this {"created_at":"2017-04-19T17:05:54Z","entry_id":4381,"field1":"1.00\r\n\r\n","field2":"83"}

How would I go about adding one more gauges?

```
<html>
  <head>

  <title>Google Gauge - ThingSpeak</title>


  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="inner">
        <div id="gauge_div"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

//css

<style type="text/css">
  body { background-color:  #FFFFFF; }
  #container { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
  #inner { }
  #gauge_div { margin: 0 auto; }
</style>


<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

  // set your channel id here
  var channel_id = 248987;
  // set your channel's read api key here if necessary
  var api_key = '16UK5LLONGR9LCR2';
  // maximum value for the gauge
  var max_gauge_value = 1023;
  // name of the gauge
  var gauge_name = 'Tlak';

  // global variables
  var chart, charts, data;

  // load the google gauge visualization
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(initChart);

  // display the data
  function displayData(point) {
    data.setValue(0, 0, gauge_name);
    data.setValue(0, 1, point);
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }

  // load the data
  function loadData() {
    // variable for the data point
    var p;

    // get the data from thingspeak
    $.getJSON('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/' + channel_id + '/feed/last.json?api_key=' + api_key, function(data) {

      // get the data point
      p = data.field1;

      // if there is a data point display it
      if (p) {
        //  p = Math.round((p / max_gauge_value) * 100);
        displayData(p);
      }

    });
  }

  // initialize the chart
  function initChart() {

    data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Label');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
    data.addRows(1);

    chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gauge_div'));
   options = {
   width: 160, height: 160, min: 955, max: 1065,
   majorTicks: [950, 980, 1010, 1040, 1060], minorTicks: 10,

   greenFrom: 955,
   greenTo: 1000,
   greenColor: "#00e600",    
   yellowFrom: 1000,
   yellowTo: 1020,
   yellowColor: "#ff751a",
   redFrom: 1020,
   redTo: 1065,
   redColor: "#FF0000"};


    loadData();

    // load new data every 15 seconds
    setInterval('loadData()', 15000);
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**first**, recommend using `loader.js` vs. the older library `jsapi`

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic `loader.js` from now on.

this will only change the `load` statement, see following snippet...

**next**, start by loading the data, before building anything else

once the json data is received, use it to determine which charts to draw,
according the properties specified by `field1`, `field2`, etc...

see following working snippet...

```js
// load the google gauge visualization
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: loadData,
  packages:['gauge']
});

function loadData() {
  // set your channel id here
  var channel_id = 248987;
  // set your channel's read api key here if necessary
  var api_key = '16UK5LLONGR9LCR2';
  // variable for the data point
  var p;
  // name of the gauge
  var gauge_name;

  // get the data from thingspeak
  $.getJSON('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/' + channel_id + '/feed/last.json?api_key=' + api_key, function(jsonData) {
    for (var key in jsonData) {
      if (jsonData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (key.indexOf('field') > -1) {
          p = jsonData[key];

          switch (key) {
            case 'field1':
              gauge_name = 'Tlak';
              break;

            case 'field2':
              gauge_name = 'Vlhkost';
              break;

            default:
              gauge_name = key;

          }

          displayData(key, p, gauge_name);
        }
      }
    }
  });

  setInterval(loadData, 15000);
}

// display the data
function displayData(div, point, name) {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Label');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
  data.addRows(1);
  data.setValue(0, 0, name);
  data.setValue(0, 1, point);

  var chartContainer = document.getElementById('gauge_div_' + div) || null;
  if (chartContainer === null) {
    chartContainer = document.getElementById('inner').appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    chartContainer.id = 'gauge_div_' + div;
    chartContainer.className = 'gauge';
  }

  var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(chartContainer);
  var options = {
    width: 160, height: 160, min: 955, max: 1065,
    majorTicks: [950, 980, 1010, 1040, 1060], minorTicks: 10,
    greenFrom: 955,
    greenTo: 1000,
    greenColor: "#00e600",
    yellowFrom: 1000,
    yellowTo: 1020,
    yellowColor: "#ff751a",
    redFrom: 1020,
    redTo: 1065,
    redColor: "#FF0000"
  };
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```css
body { background-color:  #FFFFFF; }
#container { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
#inner { }
.gauge { margin: 0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

**note**: the chart container divs are added dynamically...